# Creating a df based on total permutations deriving from user-input variables

Tags: python, pandas, string, loops, lambda

I would like to pass 'n' amount of cities to travel to and corresponding days in each city to a function that would return a df with all possible permutations of the journey. The `kayak_search_url` column in the df should contain this string in the first row:

https://www.kayak.com/flights/AMS-WAW,nearby/2023-02-14/WAW-BOG,nearby/2023-02-17/BOG-MIL,nearby/2023-02-20/MIL-SDQ,nearby/2023-02-23/SDQ-AMS,nearby/2023-02-25/?sort=bestflight_a

...but instead contains this string:

https://www.kayak.com/flights/AMS-WAW,nearby/2023-02-14/AMS-BOG,nearby/2023-02-17/AMS-MIL,nearby/2023-02-20/AMS-SDQ,nearby/2023-02-23/AMS,nearby/2023-02-25/?sort=bestflight_a

I can't figure out why the origin code 'AMS' shows up instead of the chain of cities. Here's the code:

```
# List the cities you want to travel to and from, how long you'd like to stay in each, and the appropriate start/end dates
start_city = 'Amsterdam'
end_city = 'Amsterdam'
start_date = '2023-02-14'

cities = ['Warsaw', 'Bogota', 'Milan', 'Santo Domingo']
days = [3,3,3,2]

def generate_permutations(cities, days, start_city, end_city, start_date):
    city_to_days = dict(zip(cities, days))
    
    permutations = list(itertools.permutations(cities))
    df = pd.DataFrame(permutations, columns=['city' + str(i) for i in range(1, len(cities) + 1)])
    df['origin'] = start_city
    df['end'] = end_city
    first_column = df.pop('origin')
    df.insert(0, 'origin', first_column)
    
    st_dt = pd.to_datetime(start_date)
    df = df.assign(flight_dt_1=st_dt)
    
    for i in range(len(cities)):
        df['flight_dt_' + str(i + 2)] = df['flight_dt_' + str(i + 1)] + df['city' + str(i + 1)].map(city_to_days).map(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(days=x))
    
    # IATA city code dictionary from iata_code.csv file in repo and create Kayak 'url' column for each permutation
    iata = {'Amsterdam': 'AMS',
            'Warsaw': 'WAW',
            'Bogota': 'BOG',
            'Milan': 'MIL',
            'Santo Domingo': 'SDQ'}

    url = 'https://www.kayak.com/flights/'
    df['kayak_search_url'] = df.apply(lambda x: url + ''.join([iata[x['origin']] + '-' + iata[x['city' + str(i+1)]] + \
                                                               ',nearby/' + str(x['flight_dt_' + str(i+1)].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) + '/' \
                                                               for i in range(len(cities))]) + iata[x['end']] + ',nearby/' + str(x['flight_dt_' + str(len(cities) + 1)].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) + \
                                                               '/?sort=bestflight_a', axis=1)
    
    return df
```

Comment: Exactly how should I call the function, in order to demonstrate the problem? What should the exact result be for that input, and exactly what should it be instead? Also, is it possible to simplify the code and still **demonstrate** the problem? Please read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Rather than trying to fit that much code into a `lambda`, did you try writing a named function for it and passing that to `df.apply`? Then you might be able to organize that code, split it across multiple lines, and debug it. We don't provide a debugging service here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down the desired URL to highlight its structure:

```
https://www.kayak.com/flights
    /AMS-WAW,nearby/2023-02-14
    /WAW-BOG,nearby/2023-02-17
    /BOG-MIL,nearby/2023-02-20
    /MIL-SDQ,nearby/2023-02-23
    /SDQ-AMS,nearby/2023-02-25
    /?sort=bestflight_a
```

Obviously only the middle section needs to generated as the other parts are static. We can also generate that middle section *before* constructing the dataframe:

```py
def generate_permutations(cities, days, start_city, end_city, start_date):
    iata = {
        "Amsterdam": "AMS",
        "Warsaw": "WAW",
        "Bogota": "BOG",
        "Milan": "MIL",
        "Santo Domingo": "SDQ",
    }

    permutations = [
        (start_city,) + p + (end_city,) for p in itertools.permutations(cities)
    ]
    flight_dates = pd.to_datetime(start_date) + pd.to_timedelta(
        np.array([0] + days).cumsum(),
        unit="D",
    )

    # Generate the URLs
    urls = []
    for p in permutations:
        # The pattern for each segment is
        #     START-END,nearby/yyyy-dd-dd
        mid_url = "/".join(
            [
                f"{iata[s]}-{iata[e]},nearby/{fd:%Y-%m-%d}"
                for s, e, fd in zip(p[:-1], p[1:], flight_dates)
            ]
        )
        urls.append(f"https://www.kayak.com/flights/{mid_url}/?sort=bestflight_a")

    # Generate the resulting dataframe
    return (
        pd.DataFrame(
            permutations,
            columns=["origin", *[f"city{i+1}" for i in range(len(cities))], "end"],
        )
        .merge(
            pd.DataFrame(
                flight_dates,
                index=[f"flight_dt_{i+1}" for i in range(len(flight_dates))],
            ).T,
            how="cross",
        )
        .assign(kayak_search_url=urls)
    )
```